# Firebase Realtime Database very slow on subscribe in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I have 1 question, but when I search this topic is quite old and I found no satisfactory answer. I am using [Firebase.Xamarin](https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin) to build a realtime chat application prototype. Everything looks good when I test on Android virtual machine.

However when I tested it on Xamarin iOS it was really bad. The time it takes to display data is really slow, averaging about 25-30 seconds before it shows up for the first time. Anyone got a solution for this problem? Here's what I added to the project:

```
public ObservableCollection<GetRoomChats> IteamGetRoomChats { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<GetRoomChats>();
public ObservableCollection<MyDatabaseRecord> IteamGetRoomChatsChild { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyDatabaseRecord>();

public static string FirebaseClient = "https://xxxxxxx.firebasedatabase.app/";
public static string FrebaseSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxrDkjZs";
public FirebaseClient fc = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseClient,
                   new FirebaseOptions { AuthTokenAsyncFactory = () => Task.FromResult(FrebaseSecret) });


protected async void LoadContentChat()
{
    string userid = "11111";

    var getroom = (await fc.Child("RecordsChat").OnceAsync<GetRoomChats>()).Select(x =>
    new GetRoomChats
    {
        RoomID = x.Key
    }).ToList();

    List<GetRoomChats> listroomuser = new List<GetRoomChats>();

    foreach (var room in getroom)
    {
        string str = null;
        string[] strArr = null;

        string roomget = room.RoomID;
        str = roomget + "_";
        char[] splitchar = { '_' };
        strArr = str.Split(splitchar);

        var getroomuser = strArr.Distinct().ToList();

        foreach (var item in getroomuser)
        {
            if (item == userid)
            {
                var roomgetuser = new GetRoomChats()
                {
                    RoomID = roomget
                };
                listroomuser.Add(roomgetuser);
            }
        }                
    }

    await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new PopupLoading());
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () =>
    {
        PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
        return false; // True = Repeat again, False = Stop the timer
    });

    if (listroomuser.Count() > 0)
    {
        listChats.IsVisible = true;
        lb_nullchat.IsVisible = false;

        var FirebaseClient = fc
            .Child("RecordsChat")
            .AsObservable<GetRoomChats>()
            .Subscribe((dbevent) =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    IteamGetRoomChats.Clear();
                    foreach (var room in listroomuser)
                    {
                        if (dbevent.Key == room.RoomID)
                        {
                            var lst = (await fc.Child("RecordsChat").Child(dbevent.Key).OrderByKey().LimitToLast(1).OnceAsync<MyDatabaseRecord>()).Select(x =>
                            new MyDatabaseRecord
                            {
                                NameUser = x.Object.NameUser,
                                Content = x.Object.Content,
                                RoomID = x.Object.RoomID,
                                DayCreate = x.Object.DayCreate,
                                AvatarUser = x.Object.AvatarUser,
                                sender_uid = x.Object.sender_uid,
                                receiver_uid = x.Object.receiver_uid,
                                receiver_read = x.Object.receiver_read
                            });

                            bool unread = false;
                            int countunread = 0;

                            foreach (var i in lst)
                            {
                                if (i.sender_uid == userid)
                                {
                                    i.Content = "Bạn: " + i.Content;

                                    var customerList = await apiServiceUserinfo.GetCustomersInfo(i.receiver_uid);
                                    string nameget = customerList.NameStore;
                                    string avatarget = customerList.AvatarStore;

                                    i.NameUser = nameget;
                                    i.AvatarUser = avatarget;

                                    if (i.sender_read == true)
                                    {
                                        unread = false;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (i.receiver_read == false)
                                    {
                                        i.BackgroundUser = "#f5f4f4";
                                        unread = true;

                                        countunread += 1;
                                    }
                                }

                                var last = new GetRoomChats()
                                {
                                    NameLast = i.NameUser,
                                    ContentLast = i.Content,
                                    RoomID = i.RoomID,
                                    DayCreateLast = i.DayCreate,
                                    AvatarLast = i.AvatarUser,
                                    BackgroundUnread = i.BackgroundUser,
                                    DotUnread = unread
                                };

                                IteamGetRoomChats.Add(last);
                            }

                            //IteamGetRoomChats.Add(dbevent.Object);
                        }
                    }
                });
                
            });
    }    
    else
    {
        lb_nullchat.IsVisible = true;
        listChats.IsVisible = false;
    }

    BindingContext = this;
}
```

The data on Firebase Realtime Database is really small and not worth mentioning. Looking forward to everyone's help. Thanks

Comment: You could refer to the link below about how to Optimize Database Performance. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/optimize

Comment: This is really relevant when I test on Xamarin Android it works great, it's just slow when I test on Xamarin iOS. I tested on Visual Studio OS Window Pair to Mac. Or is it related to something else. Thank you